# WebSocket client in Webview on Android kitkat v4.4.2 is not able to send messages

Tags: android, websocket, android-webview

MY hybrid Android application that communicates with an websocket server using the websocket client in Android's webview, randomly fails send  messages from server side. and this is happened only on API 19 Android devices.

can any one please help me.?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in mobile applications, it is normal to loose the connection with the server frequently, as the connectivity is not stable. Your code should check the connectivity with the server in regular intervals (every 30 or 60 seconds, for example) and reestablish the connection with the server in case of failure. I don't think that there is something special about kitkat v4.4.2. Maybe it is the device you are using that has a problem.

Comment: yes i am checking connection after every 30 seconds, also able to send request successfully, and working with another device too with same code, but problem with only 4.4.2 device, not able detect whats the problem

Comment: Without any code or log messages, it is difficult to help you.